# IIS Redirect is not working on Sitecore application

Tags: .net, iis-8, sitecore8

[image]

Attached code snippet is working for WebApi application (hosted in IIS 8.5 / 10) but it is not working for sitecore 8.2 application which hosted in same IIS server. Rather always displays Sitecore error page. Any suggestion please?

Additional info more elaborated,

When user hits https://Testing.com/wl/pages/TermsAndCondition, it should redirect to https://Testing.com/TermsAndCondition

It is working with URL Rewrite but with below url

https://Testing.com/**TestApp**/wl/pages/TermsAndCondition

where **TestApp** is set as StartItem in SiteDefinition.config but actual end user URL will be the very first one which always redirects to sitecore error page

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules You might enable FRT to see into those errors. If you plan to let others help, you need to edit the question to include more details.

Comment: Your description does not clearly provide the details of the error, it is recommended that you add more information to the question.

Comment: Did you mean: you want it to redirect to https://Testing.com/TermsAndCondition but it actually redirects to https://Testing.com/TestApp/wl/pages/TermsAndCondition and then causes a error page ?

Comment: No. I want to redirect to Testing.com/TermsAndCondition but it happens only if user hit Testing.com/**TestApp**/wl/pages/TermsAndCondition but not in Testing.com/wl/pages/TermsAndCondition

Comment: Hi, has your problem been solved?

Comment: @YurongDai Thank you Very much for your help. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the regular expression is not matching correctly.

Try changing `<match url="[0-9a-z]/wl/pages/[0-9a-z]" />`
to `<match url="([0-9a-z]*/)?wl/pages/[0-9a-z]*" />`

You can test by clicking the **Test pattern** button, you can see whether the path you entered can be matched successfully.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]